# Wordpress page loading issue

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

In my wordpress site most of the pages are takes a lots of time to load. Some time some of pages takes more than 30 seconds.
I have checked the speed issue in gtmetrix.
It's showing "PageSpeed Score" over 90% and "YSlow Score" over 75%. But page fully loaded time is 13S.

I have used "W3 Total Cache" plugin for enable cache data.
Site url : https://www.customdesignprinting.com/store/marlborough-boys-college-old-boys/

In my site I have to use "init" hooks for multiple times for different type of checking. Is it the reason behind it ?

Can you please suggest me how I can improve the page speed ?

Comment: Can you temporarily remove all the hook and see if it change the page load ?

Comment: we can't detect which cause the problem, just because it's from server side. use something like `xdebug` to detect long scripts, bad codes. try to deactivate some plugins/switch theme and etc.

Comment: also, try to look at server side logs, use some server metrics, enable debug mode to detect some errors, check sql queries time

Comment: As per google page speed testing they inform that "PSI estimates this page requires 4 additional round trips". Can you tell me how I can reduce it ?

Answer (score 0):

> Defer JavaScript loading -Deferring a file means preventing it from loading until after other elements have loaded. If you defer larger files, like JavaScript, you ensure that the rest of your content can load without a delay.If you have a WordPress site, you can the WP Rocket plugin mentioned above to easily enable deferred JavaScript loading. Simply check the box next to “Load JS files deferred,” and you’re good to go.
>
> compress your images - If you’re using WordPress, install the WP Smush.it plugin to automatically compress your images. This will reduce the size of your images without losing any visual quality.
>
> minify the javascript and css files to min.js and min.css.
> Minimize HTTP requests and try to avaoid small request and combine multiple request.
> Use asynchronous loading for CSS and JavaScript files.
> Avoid url redirections unless needed.

[read this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wordpress-performance-speed/)